# sonar with jacoco showing coverage only for testng and not for powermock

Tags: maven, testng, powermock, jacoco

We have a multi-module maven project.

Each module has couple of testng and powermock unit test cases. We are using jacoco for code coverage report. But, jacoco is analyzing unit test coverage based on testng unit test cases and ignoring powermock unit test case. So, total code coverage is coming low.

How can i configure jacoco to pick up both testng and jacoco test cases?

Comment: How did you resolve this? I also have same issue, it's showing for unit test but not for integrated test case - Kotlin files only

Answer (score 0):

PowerMock is [known](https://github.com/jacoco/eclemma/issues/15) to not work well with JaCoCo.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by bkail, jacoco and powermock instrumentation do not mix well.

I wrote an alternative maven plugin based on Cobertura that allows you to compute correctly coverage on classes covered by powermock tests. You can have a look at it (any feedback would be really appreciated) here :

https://github.com/QualInsight/qualinsight-mojo-cobertura

I'm currently trying it on a set of projects using powermock (500k NCLOC total, 110+ test classes using powermock) to detect bugs / strange behaviors, but any other feedback would be appreciated.

UT and IT coverage reports generated by this maven plugin can be directly imported into SonarQube using the generic test coverage plugin (see project's documentation), Overall coverage will be also available when the following pull request will be accepted by SonarQube :

https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-generic-coverage/pull/5

As a side note, the reasons that led to writing an alternative to the cobertura-maven-plugin is explained on the project's page.

Hope it helps !

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to generate PowerMock coverage with Jacoco, using `powermock-module-javaagent`.

Just make sure you put powermock agent **after** jacoco agent:

```
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <useSystemClassLoader>true</useSystemClassLoader>
                <argLine>${jacocoArgLine} -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/powermock/powermock-module-javaagent/${powermock.version}/powermock-module-javaagent-${powermock.version}.jar -noverify</argLine>
...
```

If you want to see an example, take a look at this project: https://github.com/jfcorugedo/sonar-scanner

Here you can see that sonar takes into account static methods and `new` statements mocked by PowerMock:

[image]

If you want to mock `new`statements make sure you use `PowerMockRule` instead of `PowerMockRunner`.

Take a look at [this test](https://github.com/jfcorugedo/sonar-scanner/blob/master/src/test/java/es/jfcorugedo/CalculatorConstructorTest.java)